# android System.gc for native code

Tags: android, garbage-collection

Let's consider below special case:

Case description:

1. Java App call jni then native mediaserver to create a instance. This native instance will use about 40M memory.
2. Java App didn't release this instance but release it in finalize (GC).
3. If many such instance created by Java App, then the memory in Java is increase but not too much, native instance will occupy N*40M memory, many memory will be consumed by native process if GC not happen in time.

Questions:

1. For this case, when will GC triggered by Java? Will GC consider the native memory increase then call GC automatically?
2. Should we call System.gc() in Java layer to release native memory? Someone seems don't agree to call System.gc() by application.
3. What's best solution to resolve such memory shortage!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, GC is a java layer concept, for native code, no such concept I guess.